# how to get a variable within a string to a python variable

Tags: python, string, variables

If I have a few strings:

```
string1 = 'text here pri=1 more text urgent=True'
string2 = 'more text here pri=5 urgent=False'
string3 = 'another text pri=3 urgent=False'
string4 = 'more text pri=10 urgent=True'
```

how can I grab the value of "pri" and "urgent" from the string to a variable?

I came up with a few solutions like for pri just locating it using str.find and then jumping 4 variables ahead, etc....

but there must be a more efficient way to read it, how can I do so?

Comment: What did you try? Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Comment: Look into [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just use the `.split()` function to get all the different words. It would return a list. For string 1:
`['text', 'here', 'pri=1', 'more', 'text', 'urgent=True']`
so now you can loop through the list and search for '='.